# Since what version of IE does it begin supporting "Find on page" command?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, winapi, mfc

I'm using [web browser control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx) in my dialog-based MFC project. I also like using the built-in IE's "find on page" functionality that brings up this window:

[image]

I can invoke it as such:

```
//pWebBrowser = pointer to IWebBrowser2
HRESULT hr;
CComVariant var1, var2;
if(SUCCEEDED(hr = pWebBrowser->ExecWB(OLECMDID_FIND, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, &var1, &var2)))
{
    //Done
}
```

This works great on my Windows 8.1 machine, but when I tried this code on an old Windows XP installation, I got this ... "thing" that totally breaks the flow in my app:

[image]

Does anyone know since what version of IE did they start supporting that "find on page" window?

Answer (score 0):

The 'find on page' functionality was introduced in IE8, which highlights all instances of found words while allowing the user to continue the navigation normally.

[Source: New features -> Inline search within pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)